# Does "also" in a simple interrogative sentence affect the subject or the verb?

Tags: word-order, questions, adverb-position, emphasis, also-too

"Should I also join the team?"

Here does "also" affect "I " (the subject) or "join" (the verb)?

Does it mean

A) Other people are joining the team and you're asking whether you should.

B) There are other activities you're pursuing and you're asking whether "joining the team" should be an additional activity.

In a declarative sentence the difference would be clear with the placement of also:

"I also should join the team." (Meaning A) - Is this grammatically correct?

"I should also join the team." (Meaning B..or A?)

Another example

"Should the infant also wear a mask?" means

A) There are grown-ups around wearing masks and you're asking whether the infant should.

B) The infant is already wearing a lot of things, you're asking whether she should additionally wear a mask.

Declarative sentences :

A) "The infant also should wear a mask." (Meaning A) - Is this grammatically correct?

B) "The infant should also wear a mask." (Meaning B or A?)

Comment: Subtle question. I feel that none of these sentences stands alone without an introductory context such as you have provided for the second pair. The *also* refers the reader’s thought to the preceding context. This is where the answer may lie, although I cannot give it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are asking the question when it's obvious that such expressions are ambiguous.